# Define grid size of ellipse

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create a plot of ellipse. My code is given below:-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math as m
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1=6.5 #Approach distane measurement point
y1=0.45 #Lateral distance measurement point
Nx=np.linspace(80,60,10)
Ny=np.linspace(80,60,10)
c=20
a=(10**(Nx/c))
b=(10**(86/20))
x=x1*(a/b) #semi major axis
Final_calculation=pd.DataFrame(x,columns = ["Distance_xaxis"])
a=(10**(Ny/c))
b=(10**(83/20))
y=y1*(a/b) #semi mionr axis
Final_calculation['Distance_yaxis']=y
Final_calculation['Sound unit decibel']=Nx
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='auto')
e1 = patches.Ellipse((0,0),x[0],y[0],linewidth=2, fill=False, zorder=2)
ax.add_patch(e1)
```

but the python shows x and y axis value only up to 1. How can I increase grid size?[image: as shown in figure].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn on autoscaling of both axes (rather than increasing the axis limits manually which is an option) using [`ax.autoscale`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html):

```
ax.autoscale(True)
```

Your code becomes

```
x1=6.5 #Approach distane measurement point
y1=0.45 #Lateral distance measurement point
Nx=np.linspace(80,60,10)
Ny=np.linspace(80,60,10)
c=20
a=(10**(Nx/c))
b=(10**(86/20))
x=x1*(a/b) #semi major axis
Final_calculation=pd.DataFrame(x,columns = ["Distance_xaxis"])
a=(10**(Ny/c))
b=(10**(83/20))
y=y1*(a/b) #semi mionr axis
Final_calculation['Distance_yaxis']=y
Final_calculation['Sound unit decibel']=Nx
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='auto')
e1 = patches.Ellipse((0,0),x[0],y[0],linewidth=2, fill=False, zorder=2)
ax.add_patch(e1)
ax.autoscale(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]